# Stop the flow to a particular task. ExecutorService

Tags: android

How can I stop a specific task in the flow when using:

```java
ExecutorService? ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool (2);
```

Service is used and brodcastReciver.

Comment: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915968/java-executorservice-pause-resume-a-specific-thread

Comment: Thanks, but do not quite understand exactly how to use the material. Can describe the main aspects?

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep references to your tasks and task should have method which stops execution. Sample:

```
TaskImpl[] tasks = new TaskImpl[2];
ExecutorService es;
tasks[0] = new TaskImpl();
tasks[1] = new TaskImpl();
es.submit(tasks[0]);
es.submit(tasks[1]);
//...
tasks[0].stop();//here you stops execution of first task
```

Comment: A stop() method that contains in itself ?

Comment: @user2366986 you must implement it. Implementation depends on your particular task.

Comment: There must be a systematic method that would stop the task. And in the method "stop ()" I'd started it. Would look like this: public void stop(){ task[0].cancel}