# How to cancel incomplete task on ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

I have submitted two tasks, `task1` & `task2` to the ExecutorService. Task2 needs 5 seconds to complete, and task1 need 10 seconds.

How can I stop the task(s) submitted (ie: task1) when task2 completes and continues the rest of logic?

Here's my code so far:

```
public class mt_poc {
    public static void action_1 () throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("action_1 invoke " );
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        action_2 ();
        System.out.println("action_1 done" );
    }

    public static void action_2() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("action_2 invoke " );
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("action_2 done " );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {                    
        System.out.println("TEST");         
        Runnable task1 = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    action_1 ();
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("action_1 invoke interrupted");
                }
                System.out.println("action_1 invoke run is over" );
                }
            }; 

        Runnable task2 = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    action_2 ();
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e) {
                   System.out.println("action_2 invoke interrupted");
                }
                System.out.println("action_2 invoke run is over" );
                }
            };          

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        try {
            executor.submit(task1);
            executor.submit(task2);
            // cancel uncomplete task 
            executor.shutdown();
            executor.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            // continues the rest of logic
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Shutdown executor");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `shutdownNow()` method

> Attempts to stop all actively executing tasks, halts the processing of
>   waiting tasks, and returns a list of the tasks that were awaiting
>   execution.

for full documentation:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

`shutdown()` method will wait for all the threads to finish before closing the executor

Answer (score 0):

You have to retrieve the `Future` objects from the `submit` function.
These are used to control the running thread and get the status of it. 
If you have the futures, call `Future2.get()`. This will block the thread until the `Task2` is finished. No you can use `Future1.cancel(true)` to abort the other thread.

But pausing and resuming is not possible. See [Java ExecutorService pause/resume a specific thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915968/java-executorservice-pause-resume-a-specific-thread)

If you want such specific behaviour you need to use Threads.

But why you want to do this in seperate Threads as it would be much simpler and efficient t use a single one.