# How to pause/resume some of the threads that running in a pool from any single thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

I am running 5 threads with ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

The problem is when any of the threads faces a problem, it must pause the other threads. Then, when the problem is solved, I want to resume the other 4 threads.

[Java ExecutorService pause/resume a specific thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915968/java-executorservice-pause-resume-a-specific-thread)

I've tried this solution but It didn't work for me or I couldn't make it work. In this answer, the pausing process not done by inside of any thread. The main thing is pausing 4 threads from inside a thread.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
int iMaxCountThread = 5;
int iCount = 0;
while (iCount < iMaxCountThread) {
     iCount++;
     Runner runner = new Runner(String.valueOf(iCount));
     Future<?> f = executor.submit(runner);
}
   ^^^^^^^^^Run in a different class' main method^^^^^^^^^^^^


        public class Runner implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run() {
              B();         
        }

        public void B(){
            if(catchesError){
                pauseOtherThreads();
                solveError();
                //When Error is solved
                resumeOtherThreads();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add all the available information like code in `pauseOtherThreads()` and `resumeOtherThreads()` in the code snippet so that it can be verified.

Comment: Can you add more background to what and why you try to do this? As mentioned in the answer your linked, canceling your current `tasks` and readding them once the problem is solved is the proper way to go.

Comment: There's no general safe way of pausing threads. You would need to use a shared mechanism (something from `java.concurrent`) that the threads would keep an eye on, and stop at when something goes wrong. But that requires that the threads can do work in chunks, and check on the shared mechanism in between.

Comment: @Kayaman hmm.. I was thinking the samething but I thought that there must be a safe way to do it. Then I will try to add some locks to the code to make the other threads busy with the locks

Comment: Have a look at [`CyclicBarrier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html). Especially in the docs you can see such sentence: `CyclicBarriers are useful in programs involving a fixed sized party of threads that must occasionally wait for each other`. And also read about [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)